# Minimum value trace of A*Atranspose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any matrix $A$, let $A^T$ denote its transpose matrix.
What is the minimum value of $\mathrm{trace}(AA^T)$ for an $n \times n$ non-singular matrix $A$ with integer entries?

Comment: You need at least $n$ nonzero entries otherwise the matrix is necessarily singular, so ${\rm tr}(AA^T)\ge n$. Then it is enough to exhibit one nonsingular matrix which attains this bound. (Hint: The obvious one works.)

Answer (score 3):

When $A$ is nonsingular, $AA^T$ is positive definite. Hence it has a positive diagonal. But $AA^T$ is also an integer matrix. Hence its diagonal entries are positive integers, meaning that $\operatorname{tr}(AA^T)\ge n$. Obviously, tie occurs when $A=I$.

Comment: +1 I like this, simple and elegant.

Comment: Quick and  accurate (+1), but requires additional knowledge about positive definitness.

Comment: @Widawensen Positive definiteness can be replaced by $(AA^T)_{ii}=e_i^TAA^Te_i=\|A^Te_i\|^2>0$, which is somewhat similar to your approach.

Comment: @user1551 That's true, you are always finding very elegant solutions..

Answer (score 1):

You can directly calculate this trace.
Let $a_1^T,a_2^T \dots a_n^T$ denote rows of $A$.

Then  on diagonal $AA^T$ you have $a_1^Ta_1,a_2^Ta_2 \dots a_n^Ta_n$.
So the sum of diagonal entries of $AA^T$ is just a sum of squares of vectors $a_i$ lengths.

More detailed picture of the situation:

$AA^T= \begin{bmatrix} a_1^T \\ a_2^T \\ \dots a_n^T \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_1  & a_2  & \dots a_n  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}{a_1^Ta_1 } & a_1^Ta_2 & \dots & a_1^Ta_n\\   a_2^Ta_1  & \color{red}{a_2^Ta_2}  & \dots   & a_2^Ta_n\\ \dots &  \dots  & \color{red}\dots  & \dots  \\ a_n^Ta_1  & a_n^Ta_2  & \dots & \color{red}{a_n^Ta_n} \end{bmatrix}$

$\operatorname{tr} (AA^T)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \color{red}{a_i^Ta_i}$.

Note additionally that vectors $a_i$ can't be zero vectors as in such situation the matrix would not be invertible. Minimal length of $a_i$ vector is therefore for integer components equal to $1$.

We have $n$ row vectors which every can have minimal length $1$. 
It's easy to find such $n$ vectors with length $1$ that they are independent linearly (in this case $A$ as $A^T$ are full rank matrices).

So the  sum of squares of lengths has minimal value $n$.

Comment: More detailed picture of the situation:

$AA^T= \begin{bmatrix} a_1^T \\ a_2^T \\ \dots \\a_n^T \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_1  & a_2  & \dots a_n  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}{a_1^Ta_1 } & a_1^Ta_2 & \dots & a_1^Ta_n\\   a_2^Ta_1  & \color{red}{a_2^Ta_2}  & \dots   & a_2^Ta_n\\ \dots &  \dots  & \color{red}\dots  & \dots  \\ a_n^Ta_1  & a_n^Ta_2  & \dots & \color{red}{a_n^Ta_n} \end{bmatrix}$

$\operatorname{tr} (AA^T)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \color{red}{a_i^Ta_i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \color{red}{\Vert a_i \Vert ^2}$.

Comment: Note additionally that vectors $a_i$
can't be zero vectors as in such a situation matrix would not be invertible. So we have the minimal length of $a_i$ vector   with  integer components equal to exactly $1$.

Comment: Identity matrix and its permutations are examples of integer invertible matrices $A$ with minimal trace of $AA^T$.

Comment: @achillehui Why to add something else? We have $n$ vectors which every can have minimal length $1$. So the the sum of squares of lengths has minimal value $n$..

Comment: The question asks for a lower bound, one should end an answer with a definite claim that address what the question is asking.

Comment: @achillehui ok. I add this definite conclusion..

Comment: +1 now the answer looks complete.

Comment: @achillehui I should learn from masters ..

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Rahul in comment, the minimum value of ${\rm tr}(AA^T)$ for non-singular $A \in {\rm Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is $n$.

Since $A = (a_{ij})$ is non-singular, $\det(A) \ne 0$. Recall $\det(A)$ can be written as a sum of $n!$ terms, one for each permutation $\pi$ of the set of $n$ symbols $[n] \stackrel{def}{=} \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$.

$$\det(A) = \sum_{\pi \in S_n}(-1)^\pi \prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\pi(k)}$$

In order for $\det(A) \ne 0$, there is at least one permutation $\pi \in S_n$  such that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\pi(k)} \ne 0
\quad\implies\quad 
a_{k\pi(k)} \ne 0,\; \forall k \in [n]\quad\implies\quad
a_{k\pi(k)}^2 \ge 1,\; \forall k \in [n]$$

This leads to
$${\rm tr}(AA^T) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^n a_{k\ell}^2
\ge \sum_{k=1}^n a_{k\pi(k)}^2 \ge \sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n$$

Since ${\rm tr}(I_nI_n^T) = {\rm tr}(I_n) = n$, this value $n$ is achievable and the minimum value of ${\rm tr}(AA^T)$ do equal to $n$.

**Notes**

There is another way to establish the bound ${\rm tr}(AA^T) \ge n$.

Recall for any $B \in {\rm Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$, the matrix $BB^T$ is positive semi-definite and all its eigenvalues are non-negative. Since $A \in {\rm Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \subset {\rm Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $A$ is non-singular,
the matrix $AA^T$ is positive definite and all its eigenvalues are positive.
Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $AA^T$. By AM $\ge$ GM, we have

$${\rm tr}(AA^T) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k \ge n \left(\prod_{k=1}^n \lambda_k\right)^{1/n} = n \left(\det(AA^T)\right)^{1/n} = n |\det(A)|^{2/n}$$

Since $A \in {\rm Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $A$ is non-singular, $\det(A)$ is a non-zero integer (in fact, equals to $\pm 1$ when $A^{-1} \in {\rm Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$). As a result,

$${\rm tr}(AA^T) \ge n 1^{2/n} = n$$

Answer (score 0):

The trace of a matrix $A$ and it's transpose is the same as the square of the frobenius norm ($\|A\|_F^2)$. So you just have to minimize the absolute value of each entry, while keeping the matrix non-singular.

The zero-matrix is obviously singular, but it's a good point to start and constructing a non-singular matrix.